# How to make a text box show a tooltip based on the input of another text box?

Tags: vb.net

I have 6 small text boxes that the user will fill with dimensions and a big text box that will automatically read from them whenever their text change event
Fires And combine their values into one string with special format.
If one of the first four text boxes is empty or not-numeric the big textbox "SecCodeTextBox" will show a tooltip error message
The problem is that the fifth textbox is allowed to be empty but not allowed to be non-numeric
So whenever the user types non-numeric characters in it
My code sets the variable that reads from it to "" to prevent copying the non-numeric value to the SecCodeTextBox and to clear any previous entry
As a result the text change event of SecCodeTextBox doesn't fires since it doesn't see any change in the variable and therefore doesn't show the tooltip however the small text box shows the tooltip just fine (I want them both to show it to be consistent with the rest of the program)
I also don't want to use the keydown event and check if e.keycode is non numeric because it will not be consistent with the rest of the program behavior
This is the code for  the fifth small textbox

```
Private Sub BbfTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BbfTextBox.TextChanged
        If BbfFocused = True Then
            ReadBbf()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReadBbf()
        prefix = PrefixComboBox.Text

        If IsNumeric(BbfTextBox.Text) Then  'if digit then store in BbfStr and in Bbf 
            ToolTipBbf.Active = False
            BbfTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Black
            BbfStr = BbfTextBox.Text
            Bbf = Val(BbfStr)
        ElseIf BbfTextBox.Text = "" Then     'if "" then = Btftextbox
            ToolTipBbf.Active = False
            BbfTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Black
            BbfStr = BtfTextBox.Text
            Bbf = Val(BbfStr)
        Else                                        'otherwise display tooltip
            ToolTipBbf.Active = True
            ToolTipBbf.SetToolTip(BbfTextBox, "Enter digits only")
            BbfTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
            AddButton.Enabled = False
            ModifyButton.Enabled = False
            BbfStr = ""
            Bbf = Val(BbfStr)

        End If
```

This is the code that should normally get called by SecCodeTextBox text change event but it doesn't

```
If secArray.GetUpperBound(0) >= 2 Then   'if there is bot fl entered
            botFl = secArray(2).Split("X")       'split element secArray(2) by "X" into botfl()


            If botFl.GetUpperBound(0) >= 1 Then    'if botfl() contains 2 elements (0) and (1) or even 3 elements in case you type XX
                If botFl(0) = "" And botFl(1) <> "" Then   'if botfl(0) only is "" return error
                    ReadSecCode = "Bbf"
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf botFl(0) <> "" And botFl(1) = "" Then 'if botfl(1) only is "" return error
                    ReadSecCode = "Tbf"
                    Exit Function
                Else                                          'else go ahead with the code
                    If IsNumeric(botFl(0)) = True Or botFl(0) = "" Then 'If botfl(0) is numeric or "" store it in BbfStr
                        BbfStr = botFl(0)
                    Else                                                'else return Bbf and exit
                        ReadSecCode = "Bbf"
                        Exit Function
                    End If
```

This is the code of the SecCodeTextBox text change event that calls the function above

```
 Private Sub SecCodeTextBox_TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecCodeTextBox.TextChanged

        errormode = ReadSecCode()

        'checks for errormode and displays appropriate tooltip
        Select Case errormode
            Case "Hw"
                SecCodeToolTip.Active = True
                SecCodeToolTip.SetToolTip(SecCodeTextBox, "Hw is invalid")
                SecCodeTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
                AddButton.Enabled = False
                ModifyButton.Enabled = False
            Case "Tw"
                SecCodeToolTip.Active = True
                SecCodeToolTip.SetToolTip(SecCodeTextBox, "Tw is invalid")
                SecCodeTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
                AddButton.Enabled = False
                ModifyButton.Enabled = False
            Case "Btf"
                SecCodeToolTip.Active = True
                SecCodeToolTip.SetToolTip(SecCodeTextBox, "Btf is invalid")
                SecCodeTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
                AddButton.Enabled = False
                ModifyButton.Enabled = False
            Case "Ttf"
                SecCodeToolTip.Active = True
                SecCodeToolTip.SetToolTip(SecCodeTextBox, "Ttf is invalid")
                SecCodeTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
                AddButton.Enabled = False
                ModifyButton.Enabled = False
            Case "Bbf"      'not working 
                SecCodeToolTip.Active = True
                SecCodeToolTip.SetToolTip(SecCodeTextBox, "Bbf is invalid")
                SecCodeTextBox.ForeColor() = Color.Red
                AddButton.Enabled = False
                ModifyButton.Enabled = False
```

I tried intentionally calling the text change event of the small text box BbfTextBox using callbyname
but I can't get it to work

Comment: Look into the [`ErrorProvder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) controls. That will make this a LOT easier.